# adding a log row log table, when the draft post publish

Tags: wpdb, wp-insert-post

i wrote some codes, about `wpdb` update query.

but update_post meta works fine but, `wpdb update` query **doesn't.**

***where am i wrong ?***

here is the code ;

```
add_action('publish_post', 'update_log_after_post_publish');
function update_log_after_post_publish($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_published_status_ = get_post_meta($post_id, 'waiting', true);
    if( empty( $post_published_status_ ) && ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_published_status_', 'published');
        // Getting post added time and author id
        $post_added_time = get_post_meta($post_id, 'postTime', true);
        $post_author_id_ = get_post_meta($post_id, 'postAuthor', true);
        // Find post log
        $logTable = $wpdb->prefix . 'mariaactivity';
        $activityText = '<i class="fa fa-folder"> <a href="'.MARIASITE.'/?p='.$post_id.'">'.get_the_title($post_id).'</a> is published now..';
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE $logTable SET type = 13 AND SET activity = $activityText WHERE time = $post_added_time AND user_id = $post_author_id_ AND type = 12");
    }
}
```

## EDIT =

I already found the solution.

`$wpdb->query("UPDATE $logTable SET type = 13 AND SET activity = $activityText WHERE time = $post_added_time AND user_id = $post_author_id_ AND type = 12");`

in this line;

i confused about using multipate SET parameters.

this line should be like this.

`SET type = 13,activity`

Comment: I already found the solution.

`$wpdb->query("UPDATE $logTable SET type = 13 AND SET activity = $activityText WHERE time = $post_added_time AND user_id = $post_author_id_ AND type = 12");`

in this line; 

i confused about using multipate SET parameters.

this line should be like this. 

`SET type = 13,activity`

Comment: Fatih, please use the _answer_ box to answer your own question. That's absolutely ok, even encouraged. Make sure you also take a look at the WYSIWYG editor buttons and browse through the [help] to see how this site works in detail. Thanks.